# Cause for ReferenceError in script

Tags: jquery

So, I have a custom js file called `"my_custom.js"` as following:

```
(function ($, root, undefined) {    
   $(function () {      
      'use strict'; 
       ///code goes here
   });  
})(jQuery, this);
```

Now, I am trying to concatenate js codes. I have a js plugin call `"someone_else.js"`

Here are two scenarios:

1. Simply load the `someone_else.js` in the footer. Everything works great.
2. Copy the code and paste into `my_custom.js`. I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: Something is not defined`

`my_custom.js` is also loaded in the footer.
The script that initialize the plugin function is also located in the footer.

What would be the cause for the error? (It always bothered me that I didn't know why it happened).

Thanks

**EDIT:**

So, here is the full setup ( I am using "blazy" http://dinbror.dk/blog/blazy/).

**Works fine:**

`blazy.min.js` is here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dinbror/blazy/master/blazy.min.js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/blazy.min.js"> </script>
<script>
  ;(function() {
   // Initialize
      var bLazy = new Blazy();
   })();
</script>
```

**Getting ReferenceError: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Blazy is not defined`**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/my_custom.js"> </script>
<script>
  ;(function() {
   // Initialize
      var bLazy = new Blazy();
   })();
</script>
```

In the `my_custom.js`, I simply added the `blazy.min.js` into my own file.

```
(function ($, root, undefined) {    
   $(function () {      
      'use strict'; 
       //blazy.min.js is copied here.
   });  
})(jQuery, this);
```

Comment: the script that initilizes the plugin function show be placed above all scripts which are using that function

Comment: Hi. I edited the question and provided the actual setup that I have.